# shell_exec mysqli is not working

Tags: php, mysqli, shell-exec

I'm calling a php script with shell_exec **that runs fully operational WHEN** called from the terminal (`php somescript.php`). However, using shell_exec I am able to check the "echo test" I'm issuing inside the script but the database queries with $mysqli are not being commited. Here is the script (again, works well when called from terminal):

```
//CALLED PHP SCRIPT
include_once("../mysqlconnection.php");

$query = "some query";

echo "this gets printed via shell_exec"

$mysqli->query($query); //this does not execute...
```

and `mysqlconnection.php`:

```
//connects well
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_ip, $db_user, $db_password, $db_database);
```

What exactly could be the problem? I call the script with `shell_exec('php some_script.php');`. Thank you very much for your help.

**EDIT:**

### As I said, **everything works well via terminal**. A couple of things:

- I have a debug function that is NOT being called although it is in mysqlconnection.php. Worst of it, if I completely mess up the code trying to provoke variable erros (like removing the include) it still "runs". Does nothing.
- If I echo in the original php script it gets printed (as in the first code example `echo "this gets printed via shell_exec"` **EVEN** if the rest of the code is messed, semicolons missing and etc. I don't really know what might be off, it's odd. It only points all the flaws if ran by terminal although it also echoes the message if called from a php script

`root
     /folder/called php script
     /script that calls the other php script
     /mysqlconnection.php`

My code is basically exactly how it is here, no need to change anything...

Comment: Does `$mysqli->query($query)` give you an error or it doesn't even reach that line?

Comment: Sorry Fane, pseudo code does not give enough information for anything other than **a guess** Show the real code. Also any errors, from the php error log

Comment: Possibly something to do with include. Are you getting any warnings or notices?

Comment: You dont seem to be interested in providing any useful information so I suggest we close this question, as UNCLEAR WHAT YOU ARE ASKING

Comment: @RiggsFolly wait please, I'm sorry I'll update the question and let you know

Comment: @RiggsFolly Updated, hope it is more detailed

Comment: @CJD Updated, hope it is more detailed

Comment: @GiamPy Updated, hope it is more detailed

Comment: (sorry for the spam)

Comment: Fane: Not really any more use then you first try. Do you believe that your real code is so special we are all going to steal you ideas?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope, neither my ideas are special but guess what, I could change this code to my real code and you wouldn't consider thinking about it either because you seem more interested in being non constructive instead of really figuring the problem. Everything is there, so the flaw can be noticed now. Please **DO** consider being helpful here.

Comment: Fane: How can I possibly help you **by making guesses**, as thats all we can do with the **mimimal information** you are supplying to us. Remember we are not **clairvoyant** and we are **not looking over your shoulder**

Comment: Ok lets take the long route! Where are you running the main script from? A web page script? A Cron job? Some other terminal process???

Comment: @RiggsFolly From a regular POST to php with no arguments. Most surely relevant.

Comment: OK so does the account that your web server runs under have permissions to access the folders that hold this code? I am assuming you are using a unix/linux

Comment: @RiggsFolly See, now you are asking the real questions!!! As I said, there is echo output from the script, so I know it is being accessed... I tried messing up the script name in `shell_exec` call (edit: and it did warn "no script with that name", I fixed it back) so I'm assuming it is being called correctly (given also the echo from the script)...

Comment: No I am having to pull relevant info from you like pulling teeth

Comment: Did you change the working directory before calling the shell_exec so that the relative file locations will work porperly. So now I am going to say let us see the actual code where you make the `shell_exec()` call

Comment: @RiggsFolly No I did not. How should I?

Comment: [The manual for cwd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: So I should run `chdir()` inside the called script? Please check my server structure is at the bottom of my question text

Comment: @RiggsFolly it F worked. it F worked. I love you man. I F love you

Answer (score -1):

> What exactly could be the problem?

Lack of error reporting.

Having errors properly reported, you will see what is wrong with your include and mysqli query.

Comment: I see, but my common sense is telling me I might already told you there are NO error reports even if I mess up the code although the echoes are **STILL** output.